# What is Put after the Equal Sign in '&source= in the LinkedIn Share Code?

Tags: javascript, window.open, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm trying to create a LinkedIn share code in my web app, but I want to understand what every part of the code means before implementing it. Take this code for example:

```
$('.lisharelink').click(function() {
  var shareurl = $(this).data('shareurl');
  window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + escape(shareurl) + '&title=' + document.title + '&source=whatever&target=new', '_blank', 'width=300,height=200');
  return false;
});
```

What should one put for `'&source=`? Where does one find the information to put here?

Comment: it's the source of the share, e.g. your website domain, or "email" or whatever, i'm pretty sure it's freetext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source would consist of YOUR Domain or any other domain the article is being shared from. It's a simple get variable.

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=[webversion]&source=YOURDOMAINHERE">
```

Comment: I guess it also isn't necessary to add it in your URL.

Comment: so if my domain is https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/rpdBQJ/, I would put `&source=https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/rpdBQJ/`? Correct?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `source`, like `title` and `summary`, is no longer acceptable for the LinkedIn share URL.  If you want to share now, the only parameter allowed is `url`, like so...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Official LinkedIn Sharing Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

However, if we look at an archive.org version of the [**Original LinkedIn Share Documentation**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160302084627/https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) (click the "Customized URL" tab), you'll see they say...

> ***SOURCE:***
>
> **description:** The url-encoded source of the content (e.g. your website or application name)
>
> **maxlength:** 200
>
> **required:** No

So, it seems like it could've been either a domain or application name, as long as it is URL-encoded and under 200 characters.

Of course, it is no longer supported by the LinkedIn API.  Just use `url` and you'll be set.  If you want to set the other fields in the share preview, you'll need to set your `og:` tags, as per [**LinkedIn Developer Docs: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).